# The differences between ssh hostname and ssh[user@]hostname

Tags: linux, ssh

When I issue `ssh -v hostname`, it tells me successful. But permission denied(publickey) when issuing `ssh -v user@hostname`. What's the differences between them? And I try to solve this problem by some ways, but weren't effective. Such as:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh/
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
Restorecon ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I guess the problem is about context, because after `issuing ssh -v hostname`, the debug information tells me unable to get valid context. And issuing `ssh[user@]hostname` it authorized id_rsa, id_ecdsa, and id_ed25519 and skiping id_dsa (probably the config setting).

Comment: I assume `user` is the same user on both machines?

Comment: What is the result of ```who am i``` on the distant server ?
Is it the same on both cases ?

See the answer below for further details on the authentication request process.

Comment: This question should be migrated over to Unix&Linux.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I will migrate it Unix&Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `user` isn't specified, the .ssh config is searched for a default one for the given host, and if there's none, the same username as on the source machine is used.

To get more information, add copy&paste of the .ssh/config and outputs of both the ssh commands.

Answer (score -1):

When using `ssh user@hostname` you explcitely try to log in as `user` on `hostname`. The login failes because you need to create an `authorized_keys` file in this user's home, too, as you did for the default user which is used when `user` is not given. Obviously authentication by password is disabled, else `ssh` would ask for it.